# how to create and update nodes and property using plain cypher?

Tags: neo4j, cypher

```
MERGE (c:contact {guid : '500010'})
ON CREATE SET
    c.data_source = '1',
    c.guid = '500010',
    c.created = timestamp()
ON MATCH SET
    c.lastUpdated = timestamp()
MERGE (s:speciality {specialtygroup_desc : 'cold'})
ON CREATE SET s.data_source = '1',
    s.specialtygroup_desc = 'fever',
    s.created = timestamp()
ON MATCH SET s.data_source = '1',
    s.specialtygroup_desc = 'comman cold',
    s.lastUpdated = timestamp()
MERGE (c)-[r:is_specialised_in]->(s)
ON CREATE SET
    r.duration = 1
ON MATCH SET
    r.duration = r.duration + 1
```

On the first run, node is created as "fever". On the second run, I have updated the specialty_group to "common cold". But it is creating new node with "fever". I am not able to update the "fever" to "common cold". What changes should I make to the above query?

Comment: Because you are searching by specialtygroup_desc but you are updating it later. Please use GUID (or unique index) to search OR do not change the value after searching.

Comment: For the second merge, you are creating a first node cold but changing it to fever because it will be new.
The second time around it will create a node cold, but it will be a new node so it will change it to fever again. you'll actually end up with two fever nodes. I'm not exactly sure what you are trying to do so would need more info to help. It looks like you're trying to do a toggle?